# Datasnap how does it handle multiple Clients

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, datasnap, tadoquery

I have a really simple DataSnap Server and a Android Datasnap client . The Server itself is configured with default values. Only the Port and IP was changed.

I have on the Server in the ServerContainer form a ADOQuery and a DataSetProvider.
I also have here a TADOStoredProcedre .

Is the DataSnap Server able to serve many clients like this ? I mean if the Same client executes the qry or the stored procedure will it work ?

Also I am a bit confused Maximum Thread Count is 0 ( unlimited )
Thread Pool is 10 , what does this mean ? Does it mean that if a Client Connects it is Assigned a Thread and inside this Thread this one client can have a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections ?

Please be gentle :)

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** ( found it via google.com )

Each client connection to the DataSnap server creates its own instances
of the ServerClass inside the server. So, as long as you use no global
variables and keep all you data inside the class you should be fine.

is this **true?**

Comment: https://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/thread/0/permalink.thr-ng2026q1910

Comment: A very nice overview of DataSnap by Paweł Głowacki. RIP.
https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/delphi-labs

Comment: Your database access components must be on a ServerMethodsUnit, not the ServerContainer unit. When the clients connect, if the lifecycle is set to "session", then each client gets it's own "copy" of the ServerMethodsUnit.

Comment: thank you . This is truly awesome and really easy to use :)